# Query - Set limit base on specific field in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

Query - Not to display data where restrict_id = 13546456566

Suppose we have a collection and in it a field name restrict_id with value 13546456566 i want not to display data any data before restrict_id have value from next it will display how can i make this query mongodb

```
  {
    "_id": ObjectID("5e9eb49efc81c83087396ff2"),
    "group_id": ObjectID("5e4e755b380054797d9db627"),
    "date": 1587459230192,
    "text": "First"
}

{
    "_id": ObjectID("5e9eb49efc81c83087396ff2"),
    "group_id": ObjectID("5e4e755b380054797d9db627"),
    "date": 1587459230192,
    "text": "Second"
}

{
    "_id": ObjectID("5e9eb49efc81c83087396ff2"),
    "group_id": ObjectID("5e4e755b380054797d9db627"),
    "restrict_id": "13546456566"
    "date": 1587459230192,
    "text": "Third"
}

{
    "_id": ObjectID("5e9eb49efc81c83087396ff2"),
    "group_id": ObjectID("5e4e755b380054797d9db627"),
    "date": 1587459230192,
    "text": "Fourth"
}
```

So here my Texture collection say you can skip thinking same Object _id its copied those are different but question is I would like to skip all first three because it has flag restrict_id = 13546456566 only to display fourth text value how this possible in mongodb

Comment: Can you edit your question to make it more understandable? Its not clear what you want to do. Also, your title talks about limit, but your question description doesnt talk about any such things

Comment: some sample data and expected output would be very helpful as well.

Comment: Yeah updated question please take a look

Answer (score 0):

The distinction of "has any previously seen document contained this value" is meaningless unless the documents are sorted.

MongoDB does not have any kind of query state variable that could be set to true and persist between documents to indicate that this has happened.

Using aggregation you could:
- sort the documents 
- push them all into an array
- reduce the array to build a new array with the condition applied
- unwind the array
- restore the documents to the state they had before

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {$sort:{sortField:1}},
  {$group:{
           _id:null, 
           documents:{$push:"$$ROOT"}
  }},
  {$project:{
             keepers:{
                $reduce:{
                         input:"$documents",
                         initialValue:{keep:false,documents:[]},
                         in:{
                              keep:{$or:[
                                         "$$value.keep",
                                         {$eq:["$$this.restrict_id","13546456566"]}
                         ]},
                         documents:{
                            $cond:[
                               "$$value.keep",
                               {$concatArrays:["$$value.documents",["$$this"]]},
                               []
                            ]}
                         }
                }
            }
  }},
  {$unwind:"$keepers.documents"},
  {$replaceRoot:{newRoot:"$keepers.documents"}}
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/3SBM_V6oP-a)

Comment: What about when there is no restrict_id ? will display all in that scenario I guess no it should display all if there is restrict_id="" or does not exist